# convert an csv file that has RGB pixel values to image

Tags: python, image, csv, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i have this  [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/srinjoybhuiya/drive-retinal-vessel-segmentation-pixelwise)  on kaggle which has the pixel values of RGB image of retina vessels as csv file
i want to convert this csv file into an image to use it in CNN in python . after which i want to hold the images in seperate npy file (X.npy ) and hold the labels (Y.npy) into another npy file to be used in CNN and colab
this is what i have been able to do so far

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra

import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\DRIVE_Modified'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('img1.csv', usecols=['R', 'G', 'B'])

print(data.shape)

print(data.head(5)) 

plt.imshow(data.to_numpy().reshape(584,565,3))

data=data.to_numpy().reshape(584,565,3)

plt.imsave('img1.png', data.astype(np.uint8))
```

any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: i updated the format